# How to localize month in DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#

I want to display my date as such: 05, August, 2020

My code:

```
string localizedDate = date.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

While debugging I see `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is {fr-CA}, but it does not write the month in French, it writes it in English.

Comment: What does `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames` show?

Comment: It's all in English.

Comment: That's the problem then. The Windows or .NET localization team has decided that the French-Canadian CultureInfo, for whatever reason, should have English month names. You're doing the right thing, it's just that the CultureInfo isn't doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var c = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
string localizedDate = date.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", c);
```

Comment: That could have significant issues in other places - if you're basically saying "I don't care about the locale, just the language" then you could end up with US-English localizations for (say) UK-English speakers. With this *particular* format string that shouldn't be an issue - but it may well be in other cases.